# How to configure comment notification such that no emails are sent in case of spam?

Tags: drupal, spam-prevention

I have a drupal 6 site running with blogs on it. I use the comment notify module to implement wordpress-like notification of new comments and the antispam module for keeping the spam off the site.

The issue I have is that commenters get email notification for **each** comment, including the spam ones, eventhough the antispam module filters those out nicely. My question: how can I configure both modules such that only email notification go out in case of ham comments? Do I need additional modules to make this happen? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not stricly programming-related, so if no-one answers here, you may try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal instead, wich is more appropriate for configuration and other webmaster-questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look there as well.

Comment: which anti spam module do you use?

Comment: @googletorp I believe it is http://drupal.org/project/antispam "...and the antispam module for keeping the spam off the site"

Answer (score 2):

Currently comment notify module and antispam module combination is not working properly. Other people have also complained about this issue: see http://drupal.org/node/598772 and http://drupal.org/node/209641

Workarounds

1. See if you can use some other comment subscription modules instead of comment notify http://groups.drupal.org/node/15928
2. See if using mollom http://drupal.org/project/mollom instead of antispam will help

Comment: Just installed Mollom, and things seem to be all set.